# More about Casting(Screen Mirroring) Technology (Protocols)

Tags: windows, casting, chromecast, dlna, miracast

So recently, Casting technology is almost poping up everywhere i know, and those Smart TVs and TV boxes starting to "claims" to support such technology, and i was like hmmm, how do they works? wat protocol they use?

and one day, as im a Nexus6P user, which built-in a feature of "Casting" on it, and my friend claims that his TV support "Casting" feature, and then he use his IPhone to drop his screen onto his tv, but when i try to open my Casting feature, it won't find the TV devices, and i tried all my devices on my hand such as PC(Chrome), and even tried some 3rd parties software, no lucks. (mostly they just use the API of phone built-in casting protocol, which is useless)

And the the funny thing is, some random video platform software in China, BiliBili found the devices and work likes a charm, with my Nexus6P, so im completely confused and did some research on Protocols of Casting Technology, here are the information i've found

Here are the protocols of Casting Technology list i got

- `DLNA/UPNP casting (Media streaming)` 
  This is probably the oldest protocol of casting technology, DLNA was originally developed for media transfer just like FTP, it probably send signal to the receiver device and ask it to receive data feed from the source, as it was not designed for Casting technology, it leaks of feature such as playback controlling and video streaming, and it need application to write its own data feeding codes, thats why there is only a few big brand software in the market support such protocol.
  (Fun facts, Windows also support this protocol hiddenly)
- `Chromecast Built-in (Google Cast)` 
  Chromecast, obviously developed by Google, and this one is directly designed for the casting technology only, such protocol seems is the leading one in the market, one fun fact is, Chromecast Built-in Projection device seems also able to cast on device that uses Miracast
- `Miracast` 
  Miracast, developed by Wi-Fi Alliance, an extend of Intel WiDi, is probably the second choice in the market, and its widely used in China as it has no relation to Google, also Windows built-in this protocol too, kinda powerful as Chromecast too
- `[Deprecated] Intel WiDi` 
  No longer supported
- `AirPlay` 
  Developed by Apple, well they have their own market thats isolated from us... watever, but this protocol is the most useful one, as AirPlay projection devices is able to project on all of the devices used any protocols above, which is really powerful, give one like to apple this time, only

Sources

- https://newsletter.icto.um.edu.mo/wireless-display-and-screen-mirroring-technology/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cast
- some random china website i forget

If there are any incorrect information or missing, plz notice me im willing to update them, im just
trying to tidy up all the protocols we have, as internet seems leak of information on such area

---

so now comes with my questions

1. as DLNA/UPNP is the oldest Screen Mirroring Technology, why google and WiFi Alliance has to develop a new protocol for casting? you might tell me because its leak of control such as playback one, but if u have ever used BiliBili, or this one i found in the PlayStore "Video & TV Cast for DLNA Player: UPnP Movie Mirror" by 2kit consulting, u will notice that actually there is some kind of way to control it, even streaming Youtube. currently i can't find any opensource project of DLNA casting player too, why is everyone dont want to update DLNA and just heading into a new way??
2. Can i use Miracast enabled projection devices to cast on a chromecast device?? Say i want to use the Windows' built-in Miracast to cast on a Chromecast Built-in device
3. Currently, casting technology also seems leak of security, you can easily project on neighbor's TV without permission, ppl even play adult video or horror video to trick the others.. why no one care about that? even google??
4. Miracast from ethernet to Wifi?? why such thing still not exist?? according the information i got from internet, the projection device must be using WiFi why??